# Collections.sort with Comparator returning constant

Tags: java, android

How bad of an idea is to reorder an ArrayList using ?

```
Collections.sort(list, descendingComparator );
```

where parameters are:

```
ArrayList<Map> list;

descendingComparator = new Comparator<Map>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Map lhs, Map rhs) {
        return -1;
    }
};
```

It seems to work, and the number of steps are not infinite,
but I am worried that this is OS version dependent.

Comment: You didn't actually implement the `compare` method properly. This really will have unpredictable output, and is JVM dependant, so it can vary across operating systems. What are you trying to do to the list? There's probably an easier way to do it.

Comment: I have a list of comparators as static members which are picked depending on the operating mode of the app, and I'm trying to avoid writing a path that doesn't use a comparator but instead stuff like Collections.reverse.

Comment: That code is in no way guarenteed to reverse your list. You'll need a more robust solution. Maybe create an abstract class `Operation` that has a method `operate` and create subclasses: ReverseOperation, ShuffleOperation, etc.

Comment: Can your list contain repeats?

Comment: @pbabcdefp it doesn't matter, I simply want a reverse order from what the original arraylist order is.

Comment: @TudorT But you won't be able to do that with a `Comparator` unless there are no repeats. For example if the original list is `[a, d, c, b]` then you just want a comparator where `b < c < d < a`. But if the original list is `[a, c, a, b]`, it's impossible because you'd need both `a < c` and `c < a`.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bad idea, because the `compare()` method is supposed to work both ways: if `a < b` then `b > a` which this comparator will not do. If `compare()` does not work like this, the results are undefined behavior. It might work, it might not, and maybe not consistently.

The ideal way is to wrap another comparator in one that reverses it:

```
final Comparator<Map> someOtherComparator = ...;
descendingComparator = new Comparator<Map>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Map lhs, Map rhs) {
        // Note the parameters are swapped here
        return someOtherComparator.compare(rhs, lhs);
    }
};
```

You could also do this:

```
Collections.sort(list, comparator);
Collections.reverse(list);
```

Finally, if your list elements have a natural ordering (implements `Comparable`, which `Map` does not), you can do this:

```
Collections.sort(list, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Comment: To be clear, what I want to do is this: for(int i=data.size()-1; i>=0; i--) { sortedData.add(map);}}, but with a comparator. It probably is best though to actually make the path split and to check when back to front reordering is needed and do the above rather than use a comparator that returns a constant.